# R function for Likelihood

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to analyze repairable systems reliability using growth models. 
I have already fitted a Crow-Amsaa model but I wonder if there is any package or any code for fitting a  Generalized Renewal Process (Kijima Model I) or type II 
in R and find it's parameters Beta, Lambda(or alpha) and q.
(or some other model for the mean cumulative function MCF)

The equation number 15 of [this article](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1006/1006.3718.pdf) gives an expression for the 
Log-likelihood

I tried to create the function like this:

```
likelihood.G1=function(theta,x){ 
# x is a vector with the failure times, theta vector of parameters
a=theta[1]  #Alpha
b=theta[2]  #Beta
q=theta[3]  #q

logl2=log(b/a) # First part of the equation

for (i in 1:length(x)){
logl2=logl2 +(b-1)*log(x[i]/(a*(1+q)^(i-1))) -(x[i]/(a*(1+q)^(i-1)))^b
}
return(-logl2)  #Negavite of the log-likelihood
}
```

And then use some rutine for minimize the -Log(L)

```
theta=c(0.5,1.2,0.8)  #Start parameters (lambda,beta,q)

nlm(likelihood.G1,theta, x=Data)
```

Or also

```
optim(theta,likelihood.G1,method="BFGS",x=Data)
```

However it seems to be some mistake, since the parameters it returns has no sense

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking at equation (16) of the paper you reference and comparing it with your code it looks like you are missing one term in the for loop. It seems that each data point contributes to three terms of the log-likelihood but in your code (inside the loop) you only have two terms (not considering the updating term)

Specifically, your code does not include the 4th term in equation (16):

[image]

and neither it does the 7th term, and so on. This is at least one error in the code. An extra consideration would be that α and β are constrained to be greater than zero. I am not sure if the solver you are using is considering this constraint.